# Django annotate with defer still uses defer column names in group by

Tags: django, group-by, annotate

It looks like `annotate()` does not take `defer()` (or `only()`) into account when building the sql query. Is this a bug or was it built like this for a reason?

Model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    a_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    a_string = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    a_date = models.DateField()
```

QuerySet:

```
Item.objects.defer(
    'a_number', 
    'a_date'
).filter(
    a_date__lte=datetime.date.today()
).annotate(
    number_sum=Sum('a_number')
).order_by("-number_sum")
```

Query:

```
SELECT "app_item"."a_string", SUM("app_item"."a_number") AS "number_sum" 
FROM "app_item" 
WHERE "app_item"."a_date" <= 2012-10-03
GROUP BY "app_item"."id", "app_item"."a_number", "app_item"."a_date", "app_item"."a_string" ORDER BY "number_sum" DESC
```

I was expecting:

```
SELECT "app_item"."a_string", SUM("app_item"."a_number") AS "number_sum" 
FROM "app_item" 
WHERE "app_item"."a_date" <= 2012-10-03
GROUP BY "app_item"."id", "app_item"."a_string" ORDER BY "number_sum" DESC
```

I know I can use `values()` but I would like model instances.

Maybe there is an easy way to remove group by columns as I still would like to remove "app_item"."id" fom group by as well?

I am going to use raw for now but would be nice to have a cross db solution.

Comment: In case you're using special expressions from `django.db.models.expressions` (like `RawSQL`) you can overwrite them and return different values for `get_group_by_cols()`. I think something similar must be possible for other lookups.